# What does "tmux ls" mean in tmux

Tags: tmux

I am not very familiar with tmux but it runs for everyday work.

Sometimes, I input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, then the tmux window disappears and the screen shows

```
xxx@bsa0248:~$ tt
[detached (from session 3)]
```

Then if I input the following command, I get some strange output:

```
xxx@bsa0248:~$ tmux ls
0: 3 windows (created Sun Jun 10 16:39:33 2018) [123x32]
1: 3 windows (created Sun Jun 10 16:43:10 2018) [123x32]
2: 3 windows (created Sun Jun 10 17:14:23 2018) [98x29]
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Related OS is Ubuntu

```
xxx@bsa0248:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 9.10 \n \l
```

Answer (score 7):

`tmux ls`, which is an alias for `tmux list-sessions`, lists all the active sessions managed by the `tmux` server you’re connected to.

The output you’re getting means there are three sessions running, each with three windows. The numbers between square brackets show the terminal size of each session.

When working on multiple tmux sessions, it's useful to initialized them with a name, using

```
tmux new -s SessionName
```

so that in the list you'll see the `SessionName` instead of a number in the first column of the output of `tmux ls`. Of course you can also rename an already-open session, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/428016/how-do-i-rename-a-session-in-tmux).

Comment: Hi Kitt, 
Thank you for your reply. I see now.
But recently I find tmux ls can't work and error output is below: 

Do you know why? Thanks

@bsa0483:~$ tt
[detached (from session 0)]
Tom@bsa0483:~$ tmux ls
server not found: No such file or directory
Tom@bsa0483:~$
Tom@bsa0483:~$ tmux list-sessions
server not found: No such file or directory
Tom@bsa0483:~$

Comment: That means it can’t find your server, but I don’t know why.